# how can we link one jsonschema to another jsonschema

Tags: json, jsonschema, reusability

path of the file is `E:\JSONSchema\Files\details.json`

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "tagid": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "id",
      "tagid"
    ],
    "additionalProperties": false
  }
}
```

I want to reuse the above `jsonschema` in another file which is located in `E:\JSONSchema\Core\visuals.json`. How can I proceed to achieve it?

Comment: Separate from your question, there was an error in your example schema. The schema was invalid because the "required" property appears as an element of the "properties" list. "required" needs to be a top-level property of the schema object, at a sibling level with "properties." I submitted an edit to your question, and it was just approved.  For the record, here's a gist, shown in JSON Schema Lint: http://jsonschemalint.com/#/version/draft-05/markup/json?gist=8a3c1b3b0264899879c1fecab6ba8ed4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$ref` and provide an absolute path as a value

Example:

file path: `E:\JSONSchema\Files\details.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "reuse": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "tagid": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "id",
        "tagid"
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
}
```

If I want to reuse in another file the sample code will look like

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "IDs": {
      "$ref": "file:/E:/JSONSchema/Files/details.json#/reuse"
    }
  }
}
```

Another way of achieving this is by using `id`. 
Check the following code.

```
{
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
      "id": "file:/E:/JSONSchema/Files/details.json",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "firstName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "lastName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "IDs": {
          "$ref": "#/reuse"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your `$ref` points to `#/reuse`, which I believe is undefined.  Everything after the `#` is a JSON pointer within a document.  Since you included the hash fragment without a file reference preceding it, this would look for a `reuse` element in the root object of the _current_ schema.  If you want to reference `reuse` in an external schema, you have to include a URI that points to that schema, followed by the hash sign and JSON pointer.

Answer (score 0):

JSON Schema allows externally defined schemas to be referenced using an object with a single `$ref` property, wherever a schema object is expected.  The relevant section of the spec is [here](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.7):

> Any time a subschema is expected, a schema may instead use an object
>   containing a "$ref" property. The value of the $ref is a URI
>   Reference. Resolved against the current URI base, it identifies the
>   URI of a schema to use. All other properties in a "$ref" object MUST
>   be ignored.

So to follow your example, this should work as the content of `e:\JSONSchema\Core\visuals.json`:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "IDs": {
      "$ref": "../files/details.json"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit and answer. But, when I tried your solution I got an error like the `URI is not absolute`. So, I tried to provide absolute path. Please check me answer and let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: I think relative URIs should work, but I don't have a good environment to test that (other than writing my own test harness).  What are you using to test?

Comment: I am using `jackson` api to test in `java` environment